# How to export field collection with Drupal 7 views data export plugin?

Tags: importing-exporting

The Views Data Export plugin appears to work perfectly with the data that I have, though I have a field called "Items Bought" consisting of fields ("Item Bought" and "Cost"). For each content type of type "ShoppingRecord" a user could have one or more "Items Bought" field collections (i.e. Bannana $2, Apple $5).

When I add the field to my "page". I noticed that when I create a view with the "Data Export" and use CSV as the option, I am getting blanks for all the rows in the "Items Bought" column. Is there some way to get the plugin to recognize field collections and maybe export them all into the same field in the CSV? All the other fields that are not field collections appear to export properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the first result you can add a relationship in the view. Search for the name of the field collection. Once you add this relationship you should be able to access the field collection items and add them to your output.

If you want all the values you need to search add the field collection to your view rather than the fields directly. You then have the options of how to display the results but these options are limited.